# How are double quotes handled in c# string data coming from streamreader

Tags: c#

I have the following code in a much larger project:

```cs
using (Stream dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(dataStream))
    {
        output = (String)rdr.ReadToEnd();
        rdr.Close();
    }
    // Close up everything...
    dataStream.Close();
}
```

Variable `output` is being loaded with data from a CSV file that is quote-delimited and escaped similar to JSON IE:

```
"abc","def","g\"hi"
```

The question is: What happens to these double quotes in `output`? Are they converted to doubled-double quotes like this
`""abc"",""def"",""g\""hi""`
I ask as I need to handle the escaped quote shown in

```
"g\"hi"
```

Comment: `StreamReader` won't do any escaping or unescaping. Don't be fooled by the debugger - that *will* escape things. If you print the results to the console instead, you should be fine.

Comment: Note that the `(String)` cast is superfluous as `ReadToEnd` returns a string.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-8.0

Comment: As are the calls to `rdr.Close()` and `dataStream.Close()` given the `using` statements.

Comment: You may also want to consider using a specific CSV library such as CsvHelper for working with CSV files.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for that - exactly what I was trying to understand. Also yes some of the calls are extraneous but I do not have the ability to edit this larger project.... At least not yet :-)

Answer (score 2):

The reason we have to escape characters is because certain characters are ambiguous:
A double quote could be part of a string, or it could be the end/start of a string. the compiler needs to be certain, thats why characters are escaped.

The reader does not care about escaping characters, because it simply does not concern him. So he will return the content of whatever he reads just as it is.
If thats a double quote, it will simply be a double quote.